# Can you easy structure company - groups - users - permissions in symfony

Tags: symfony

If I need to build a site where I need to be able to create multiple companies and each company can have multiple groups of users
Groups can then have permissions

So a user that belongs to "publisher" group in companyA does not have access to same things and "publisher" group in companyB

I wonder if that is built into symfony?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the [cookbook ;)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html)

You can use [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) or the more complex [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html).

With voters, you can call a service wich will contain the business logic of yours